# How can I save the picture in the gallery

Tags: java, android

My camera app makes photos but they always get saved in the app and I want to see them in the Gallery, but I want to stay with ImageCapture. I use Android 14.

```java
public void takePicture(ImageCapture imageCapture) {
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file).build();
    imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onImageSaved(ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image saved at: " + file.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                startCamera(cameraFacing);
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onError(ImageCaptureException exception) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to save: " + exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                startCamera(cameraFacing);
            }
    
        });
```

Comment: `they always get saved in the app and I want to see them in the Gallery` Two misconceptions. An app cannot save files in itself. Only to storage locations of the device. Further you cannot store in the gallery as an alp can store only files in the storage of the device. Once the files land in the device storage they can be scanned by the media store. Gallery apps request the media store to give a list of pictures.

Comment: getExternalFilesDir() is private storage of your app. It will not be scanned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to save an image into your Downloads/AppName folder:

```
   try {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/AppName");
        File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator);
        if (!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdir();
        }

        //Create file..
        File file = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "fileName" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg");
        file.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.write(bytes);
        out.close();

        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "File Downloaded...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // OPENING FOLDER LOCATION

        // getting download/appName folder permission

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/AppName";
            File folder = new File(path);
            String startDir = "", secondDir, finalDirPath;

            if (folder.exists()) {
                startDir = "Download%2FAppName";
            }

            StorageManager sm = (StorageManager) requireContext().getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);

            Intent intent = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent();

            Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI");

            String scheme = uri.toString();

            scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/document/");

            finalDirPath = scheme + "%3A" + startDir;

            uri = Uri.parse(finalDirPath);

            intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri);

            startActivity(intent);

        }else{
            Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(),
                    requireContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
                    file);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(data, "application/jpeg");

            startActivity(intent);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No apps found to open downloaded file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("error", "downloadPdf: error" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have two more Questions. First one is how I can change how big the picture is in the files its only 1 byte and i think thats why I cant open it. Secondly this gets marked Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No apps found to open downloaded file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); and i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: @Huraweurg Make sure to convert your imageCapture into bytes before donwloading the file. Kindly send me your logcat details so that I can help you to resolve that error?

Comment: I solved the problem thanks for your help